# Mounting Solaris UFS partition on Debian(with FreeBSD kernel)

Tags: debian, solaris, freebsd, ufs

I have some disks that were being used on a Solaris system. The disks are formatted as UFS.
I attached them to a Debian system (with FreeBSD kernel. Debian/kFreeBSD), but I cannot mount them.

```
$ mount -t ufs /dev/da2s1 /mnt/diska
mount: /dev/da2s1 : Invalid argument
```

Also the tunefs.ufs does not work;

```
$ tunefs.ufs -p /dev/da2s1
tunefs.ufs: /dev/da2s1: could not read superblock to fill out disk
```

Is there an incompatibility between FreeBSD UFS and Solaris UFS? Is it possible to mount one, under the other OS ?

**Note**: tunefs.ufs works on the root partition

```
$ tunefs.ufs -p /dev/da7s2
tunefs.ufs: ACLs: (-a)                                         disabled
tunefs.ufs: MAC multilabel: (-l)                               disabled
tunefs.ufs: soft updates: (-n)                                 disabled
tunefs.ufs: gjournal: (-J)                                     disabled
tunefs.ufs: maximum blocks per file in a cylinder group: (-e)  2048
tunefs.ufs: average file size: (-f)                            16384
tunefs.ufs: average number of files in a directory: (-s)       64
tunefs.ufs: minimum percentage of free space: (-m)             8%
tunefs.ufs: optimization preference: (-o)                      time
tunefs.ufs: volume label: (-L)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeBSD UFS2 and Solaris UFS, while sharing some original structure have somewhat diverged so I'm unsure freeBSD can mount it. Was your UFS file system properly unmounted ?

EDIT: Also, if the file system was created on SPARC hardware, it won't be mountable on x86 as the format is architecture dependent.

Comment: I mounted and unmounted under solaris but it did not work. I also wanted to try read-only UFS code in Linux, but it alse gave errors. I guess solaris UFS is very lonely :-/

Comment: Also, the UFS was created on x86 hardware.

Comment: Most Gnu/Linux distributions should be able to directly mount in read-only mode an ufs slice created on Solaris running on x86 hardware. eg: "mount -r /dev/sdb5 /mnt".

Answer (score 0):

Did you halted the solaris system without the unmount?

As far as I know you can safely mount a cleanly-unmounted Solaris UFS, otherwise it's really a layout compatibility issue. I'd try to do the same also with a recent GNU/Linux kernel

Comment: I have tried explicitly mounting and umounting the disks. But I still get the same message. I tried mounting in Ubuntu, but It gave an error message about superblock's magic number(can't remember exact message)